# Passing arguments of a function to another function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a method defined, say `abc`, which accepts a function name, say `xyz` and the arguments to that function as its arguments. Now, the `abc` method needs to call `xyz` with the arguments received.

`xyz` can be any method and could be having any number of arguments, also, `xyz` cannot be using arguments keyword. rather, the arguments for the method should be passed as separate variables.

Ex: `xyz` will be defined as:

```
var xyz = function(a,b){//code for processing a and b}
```

I am calling the `abc` method with the first argument as the function to be invoked and rest of the arguments as arguments to be passed to the function while calling it. In `abc`, I am making use of arguments keyword to access the dynamic number of arguments sent. But from there I am not sure how to call the next function with the arguments.

Comment: instead of explaining can you post the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `apply` method of functions to call it with a variable argument list:

```
function abc(funcName) {
    funcName.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

You could also pass along your current context by supplying the first argument:

```
function abc(funcName) {
    funcName.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

Comment: my funcName will be present in the arguments variable. Since array operations are not supported in javascript how can i remove the first argument and pass the rest of the arguments to funcName function?

Comment: I fixed the answer to use `arguments.slice(1)`.